# Java - netty library execution time very big - Java NIO

Tags: java, profiling, netty, execution-time, java-nio

I am developing a Java application that reads data from a `Redis` Database, I use `Lettuce` library to connect to `Redis` which in turn uses 'Netty' library to communicate with `Redis`
I suspect that the execution time of my application is greater than expected, so a conducted a profiling experiment using `JProfiler`, I was surprised that a `FastThreadLocalRunnable` takes a significant portion of the execution time with no justification as the tree shows no function calls taking time:

[image: Screenshot from JProfiler after some long time of execution]

So, is it a bug in `Lettuce` library?, or is it a problem in the profiler measuring the execution time?

Any help is appreciated

---

Edit:

Thanks to Ingo's answer I can now expand the tree but it turns out that the java NIO is consuming my processor:

[image: Java NIO is taking the processing power]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call tree in JProfiler only shows classes that are included in the call tree filters that you define in the profiling settings:

[image]

By default, this excludes a lot of common frameworks and libraries so that you can get started without configuring anything. It is better if you delete these filters and add your own profiled packages here.

In addition to the profiled classes, JProfiler shows the thread entry point even it is not a profiled class, such as `io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable`. Also, the first call into non-profiled classes is always shown at any level in the call tree.

In your case there are call chains to non-profiled classes below `io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable` that never call a profiled class. They could belong to some framework or to some part of your code that is not included in the profiled classes. This time has to go somewhere, so it is attributed to the `io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable` node.

An easy way to check is to disable filtering in the profiling settings, then you see all classes.

[image]

More information about call tree filters can be found at

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/main/methodCallRecording.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, deleting the filter reveals the real cause that is the NIO selector which is really weird, should Java NIO consume that much CPU power?

Comment: The JVM does not reports these methods as non-blocking, so JProfiler builds it own Net I/O thread state for that. Since JProfiler 11 this method is part of the Net I/O thread state and should not show in the "Runnable" thread state in this way. Can you try it with the current version of JProfiler?